Is there an generalisation of convolution theorem to integral transforms
Basic convolutions can be computed efficiently by taking fourier transforms and applying the convolution theorem. Is there something analogous for a more general transform, where we have a varying kernel:
$$
h(y)=\int_{}^{}f(x)g(x-y,y)dx
$$
The standard convolution theorem no longer applies as the shifting property can't be used.
A couple things I've tried that haven't worked so far:
-use something other than the Fourier transform which has a property allowing the functions to be separated
-expand the kernel in a basis (e.g. hermite functions) and exploit a property of the basis functions

this is equivalent to asking how to efficiently compute the integral $\int f(x)h(x,y),dx$; there is nothing you can say in general, without knowledge of the function $h(x,y)=g(x-y,y)$.
